# Node JS+passport Authentication+multiple user types

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, google-authentication

I am new to Node.js.

In my application I have two types of user roles. 
One is trainer and another one is client.

I need to implement social authentication for both users in two different pages. 
At first i had developed authenticating trainers using passport authentication.
Developed facebook, google and linked in signups.

Now i want to develop the same to clients also. For this I would like to create seperate callback URLS and seperate apps.

How can I proceed with configuring different callbacks for clients with passport authentication.

Can anyone please help with this issue.

Comment: What is "passport authentication"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a middleware to check if a user is a trainer.  The advantage of this is that it would optionally allow a trainer to be a client as well  within one profile.  (maybe the yoga instructor wants to take some spinning classes)

```
     var isUserTrainer = function() {
            if (req.user && req.user.isTrainer === true) {
                next();
            } else {
                res.send(401);
            }
        };

app.all('/trainer/*', isUserTrainer()); //use on all request to /trainer/*
app.get('/trainer/', isUserTrainer, function(req, res) {...}); // use on specific route
```

And you would just need to add `isTrainer` to your user schema.